# how to save my phonenumber contact details in sim card android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

how to save my phonenumber contact details in sim card android?.I want to add contact details directly in sim,not in phone.I am using the below code to save contacts in phone.But facing problem in saving in sim.how i can i acheive this???

I am using the following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Creating a button click listener for the "Add Contact" button
        OnClickListener addClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Getting reference to Name EditText 
                EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);

                // Getting reference to Mobile EditText 
                EditText etMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mobile_phone);

                // Getting reference to HomePhone EditText 
                EditText etHomePhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_home_phone);

                // Getting reference to HomeEmail EditText 
                EditText etHomeEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_home_email);

                // Getting reference to WorkEmail EditText 
                EditText etWorkEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_work_email);     


                ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
                          new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                int rawContactID = ops.size();


            // Adding insert operation to operations list 
                // to insert a new raw contact in the table ContactsContract.RawContacts
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert display name in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, etName.getText().toString())
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert Mobile Number in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, etMobile.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to  insert Home Phone Number in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, etHomePhone.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert Home Email in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, etHomeEmail.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME)
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert Work Email in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, etWorkEmail.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
                        .build());          

                try{
                    // Executing all the insert operations as a single database transaction

                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contact is successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (RemoteException e) {                    
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               }
        };


        // Creating a button click listener for the "Add Contact" button
        OnClickListener contactsClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Creating an intent to open Android's Contacts List
                Intent contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

                // Starting the activity
                startActivity(contacts);                
            }
        };


        // Getting reference to "Add Contact" button
        Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

        // Getting reference to "Contacts List" button
        Button btnContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_contacts);

        // Setting click listener for the "Add Contact" button
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(addClickListener);

        // Setting click listener for the "List Contacts" button
        btnContacts.setOnClickListener(contactsClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the actual problem? For example, incorrect information is saved, nothing is saved, an error message is produced ...

Comment: i am able to save in phone.but dont know how to save in simcard???

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this permissions to Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

And try this code:

```
 private void addContactToSim(String number, String name) 
 {
 Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put("number", number);
 values.put("tag", name);
 getContentResolver().insert(simUri, values);
 }
```

When you saving in phone you can save a lot of fields for example  First name, Surname, email, adress, add more than one number. And when you saving in Sim-card you have only two fields *Name* and *Number*.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.android.contacts.sim")
                        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "SIM")
                        .build());
```

Comment: What if there is more than one SIM card, or none? How can I check it and also save on the one the user chose?